# How to pause android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I'm playing text with android TTS - `android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech`

I use: `TextToSpeech.speak` to speak and `.stop` to stop. Is there a way to pause the text also?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The TTS SDK doesn't have any pause functionality that I know of.  But you could use [`synthesizeToFile()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29) to create an audio file that contains the TTS output.  Then, you would use a [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) object to play, pause, and stop playing the file.  Depending on how long the text string is, it might take a little longer for audio to be produced because the `synthesizeToFile()` function would have to complete the entire file before you could play it, but this delay should be acceptable for most applications.

Comment: Please let me know how we can know when to pause the mediaPlayer? For eg: If the string has a pause after 50 characters how do we know at what position we need to pause the mediaPlayer?

Comment: This is the accepted answer? Seems way more complicated. How are you gonna know exactly when to pause?

Answer (score 15):

I used splitting of string and used playsilence() like below:

```
public void speakSpeech(String speech) {

    HashMap<String, String> myHash = new HashMap<String, String>();

    myHash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "done");

    String[] splitspeech = speech.split("\\.");

    for (int i = 0; i < splitspeech.length; i++) {

        if (i == 0) { // Use for the first splited text to flush on audio stream

            textToSpeech.speak(splitspeech[i].toString().trim(),TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, myHash);

        } else { // add the new test on previous then play the TTS

            textToSpeech.speak(splitspeech[i].toString().trim(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,myHash);
        }

        textToSpeech.playSilence(750, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much.. Its working for me.. but I am facing a problem that its leaving the word which I am passing to speech.split("xyz"). example I ahve sentence as "Android and Java" and speech.split("and") then It first play "Android" then pause for given time and then plays "Java". Its leaving and without playing

Comment: Split on space,
i.e. speech.split("\\s+")

Comment: add \n in string where you want pause

Answer (score 7):

You can make the TTS pause between sentences, or anywhere you want by adding up to three periods (".") all followed by a single space " ".  The example below has a long pause at the beginning, and again before the message body. I'm not sure that is what you are after though.

```
    private final BroadcastReceiver SMScatcher = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            // if(message starts with SMStretcher recognize BYTE)
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            /*
             * The SMS-Messages are 'hiding' within the extras of the
             * Intent.
             */
            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle != null) {
                /* Get all messages contained in the Intent */
                Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
                SmsMessage[] messages = new SmsMessage[pdusObj.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                    messages[i] = SmsMessage
                            .createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                }
                /* Feed the StringBuilder with all Messages found. */
                for (SmsMessage currentMessage : messages) {
                    // periods are to pause
                    sb.append("... Message From: ");
                    /* Sender-Number */
                    sb.append(currentMessage.getDisplayOriginatingAddress());
                    sb.append(".. ");
                    /* Actual Message-Content */
                    sb.append(currentMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());
                }
                // Toast.makeText(application, sb.toString(),
                // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                if (mTtsReady) {
                    try {
                        mTts.speak(sb.toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,
                                null);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(application, "TTS Not ready",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
};
```

If you omit the space after the last period it will (or may) not work as expected.

Comment: this vary on different TTS

Answer (score 6):

I used a different approach.

1. Seperate your text into sentences
2. Speak every sentence one by one and keep track of the spoken sentence
3. pause will stop the text instantly
4. resume will start at the beginning of the last spoken sentence

Kotlin code:

```
class VoiceService {

    private lateinit var textToSpeech: TextToSpeech    

    var sentenceCounter: Int = 0
    var myList: List<String> = ArrayList()

    fun resume() {
        sentenceCounter -= 1
        speakText()
    }

    fun pause() {
        textToSpeech.stop()
    }

    fun stop() {
        sentenceCounter = 0
        textToSpeech.stop()
    }

    fun speakText() {

        var myText = "This is some text to speak. This is more text to speak."

        myList =myText.split(".")

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        textToSpeech.speak(myList[sentenceCounter], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, utteranceId)
            sentenceCounter++
        } else {
            var map: HashMap<String, String> = LinkedHashMap<String, String>()
            map[TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID] = utteranceId
            textToSpeech.speak(myList[sentenceCounter], TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, map)
            sentenceCounter++
        }
    }

    override fun onDone(p0: String?) {
        if (sentenceCounter < myList.size) {
            speakText()
        } else {
            speakNextText()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @rm -rf, coudl you please share  what is utteranceId ?

Comment: Hi @rm -rf, could you please share what is utteranceId and speakNextText() method?

Comment: Where is `speakNextText()` defined?

Answer (score 5):

In the absence of a pause option, you can add silence for the duration of when you want to delay the TTS Engine speaking. This of course would have to be a predetermined 'pause' and wouldn't help to include functionality of a pause button, for example.

For API < 21 : [public int playSilence (long durationInMs, int queueMode, HashMap params)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#playSilence(long,%20int,%20java.util.HashMap%3Cjava.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%3E))

For > 21 : [public int playSilentUtterance (long durationInMs, int queueMode, String utteranceId)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#playSilentUtterance(long,%20int,%20java.lang.String))

Remember to use [TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#QUEUE_ADD) rather than [TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#QUEUE_FLUSH) otherwise it will clear the previously started speech.

Answer (score 4):

I haven't yet tried this, but I need to do the same thing.  My thinking is to first split your speech text into an array of words.

Then create a recursive function that plays the next word after the current word is finished, while keeping a counter of the current word.

Comment: This will result in a choppy output. Even though the TTS engines are not that great at intonation, saying one word at a time will not give them any chance to put there the intonations the engines are capable of. Synthesizing one sentence at a time is the way.

Answer (score 3):

divide the `messages` into parts and listen for last `utterance` by using `onutteranceprogress` listener

```
 tts.playSilence(1250, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that if you put a period after a word AND start the next word with a capital letter, just like a new sentence, like this:

**after we came home. We ate dinner.**

the "home. We" will then have a pause in it.

- This becomes a grammatically strange way of writing it.
- So far I have only tested this in my own language, Swedish.
- It might be important that the space is there.

Answer (score 0):

Also, an escaped quote (\") seems to have it pause somewhat as well - at least, if you put it around a word it adds space around the word.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is not perfect,  but an alternative to @Aaron C's solution may be to create a custom text to speech class like the below. This solution may work well enough if your text is relatively short and spoken words per minute is accurate enough for the language you are using.

```
private class CustomTextToSpeech extends TextToSpeech {
    private static final double WORDS_PER_MS = (double)190/60/1000;

    long startTimestamp = 0;
    long pauseTimestamp = 0;

    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable speakRunnable;

    StringBuilder textToSpeechBuilder;

    private boolean isPaused = false;

    public CustomTextToSpeech(Context context, OnInitListener initListener){
        super(context, initListener);

        setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDone(String arg0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "tts done. " + arg0);
                startTimestamp = 0;
                pauseTimestamp = 0;
                handler.postDelayed(speakRunnable, TTS_INTERVAL_MS);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String arg0) {
                Log.e(TAG, "tts error. " + arg0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(String arg0) {
                Log.d(TAG, "tts start. " + arg0);
                setStartTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
        });

        handler = new Handler();

        speakRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                speak();
            }
        };

        textToSpeechBuilder = new StringBuilder(getResources().getString(R.string.talkback_tips));
    }

    public void setStartTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        startTimestamp = timestamp;
    }
    public void setPauseTimestamp(long timestamp) {
        pauseTimestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public boolean isPaused(){
        return (startTimestamp > 0 && pauseTimestamp > 0);
    }

    public void resume(){
        if(handler != null && isPaused){
            if(startTimestamp > 0 && pauseTimestamp > 0){
                handler.postDelayed(speakRunnable, TTS_SETUP_TIME_MS);
            } else {
                handler.postDelayed(speakRunnable, TTS_INTERVAL_MS);
            }
        }

        isPaused = false;
    }

    public void pause(){
        isPaused = true;

        if (handler != null) {
            handler.removeCallbacks(speakRunnable);
            handler.removeMessages(1);
        }

        if(isSpeaking()){
            setPauseTimestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        }

        stop();
    }

    public void utter(){
        if(handler != null){
            handler.postDelayed(speakRunnable, TTS_INTERVAL_MS);
        }
    }

    public void speak(){
        Log.d(TAG, "textToSpeechBuilder: " + textToSpeechBuilder.toString());
        if(isPaused()){
            String[] words = textToSpeechBuilder.toString().split(" ");
            int wordsAlreadySpoken = (int)Math.round((pauseTimestamp - startTimestamp)*WORDS_PER_MS);
            words = Arrays.copyOfRange(words, wordsAlreadySpoken-1, words.length);

            textToSpeechBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            for(String s : words){
                textToSpeechBuilder.append(s);
                textToSpeechBuilder.append(" ");
            }
        } else {
            textToSpeechBuilder = new StringBuilder(getResources().getString(R.string.talkback_tips));
        }

        if (tts != null && languageAvailable)
            speak(textToSpeechBuilder.toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, new Bundle(), "utter");
    }
}
```

Comment: where is tts reference?

Comment: What is TTS_INTERVAL_MS and TTS_SETUP_TIME_MS ?

Comment: TTS_INTERVAL_MS will repeat the spoken text in this defined interval interval. You can change to .post instead of .postDelayed if this is not desired (just helps with testing pause&resume with your text ). TTS_SETUP_TIME_MS is the amount of time delay you want to wait until the text is uttered.