# Text-To-Speech STOP Issue

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have an activity in which there is a continuous updation of display on the screen and also updation of text to speech. The problem here is while the UI is updating, if I press home button then also the text to speech is not stopped. It is running continuously. I have tried to write the `stop()` and also `shutdown()` in `pause()` and also in `destroy()` but still its not working. Can anyone please let me know how to stop that?

Please help me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is hard to tell without looking at your code what you are doing wrong, but you should be able to call [TextToSpeech.stop()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#stop%28%29) or [TextToSpeech.shutdown()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#stop%28%29) in your `onPause` and make that work. It is possible the stop fails for any number of reasons, and if it does then you're just out of luck. This works for me consistently on 6 different models of Android device (`mTts` is my `TextToSpeech` instance):

```
@Override
    protected void onStop()
    {
        super.onStop();

        if(mTts != null){
            mTts.shutdown();
        }       
    }
```

Comment: I tried this too but it didnt work. I have made mTts shutdown in onStop() and tried, onPause() and tried and also in onDestroy() tried

Comment: thanks a lot... This worked for me now... Before I have tried with many tts objects thats why it didnt work. If i am working on a single tts object then its working absolutely fine

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null) {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();

    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

(try do like this code, it's work with me)

Answer (score 1):

The TTS SDK doesn't have any pause functionality that I know of. But you could use `synthesizeToFile()` to create an audio file that contains the TTS output. Then, you would use a MediaPlayer object to play, pause, and stop playing the file. Depending on how long the text string is, it might take a little longer for audio to be produced because the `synthesizeToFile()` function would have to complete the entire file before you could play it, but this delay should be acceptable for most applications.

Comment: its different its a wastage to again store it and again retrieveing.... I dont want like this

Comment: Are you sure about it because many tts applications are there and i dont understand why is the stop() or shutdown() not working as how it should

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970204/how-to-pause-android-speech-tts-texttospeech