# How to give pause or gap between words in TTS in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I have given a text in `mytts.speak("hi hello hi",parameter,parameter...);`

But the words are continuously said without any gap or pause, I want to provide some time gap between words for more clarity.

How could I achieve this ?

Comment: 1 second will do it.In emulator by giving'/' i cud achieve this but when i run it on sumsung device ,the behaviour is changed.

Comment: agree different devices, different behavior of TTS. Even somtimes voice quality is different.

Comment: I would like to target on sumsung devices,how could we generalize TTS on all devices

Comment: How about spliting words from `hi hello hi` sentence and play on tts ?

Comment: could you provide some sample code of what you mean by splitting words

Comment: http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/09/string-split-example-in-java-tutorial.html

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970204/how-to-pause-android-speech-tts-texttospeech) thread has the answer (by rushi).

Simply add a delay into the TTS queue by splitting the string and loop over the snippets via a for loop:

```
mytts.speak(snippet, QUEUE_ADD, null);
mytts.playSilentUtterance(2000, QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply add a comma everywhere you want there to be pauses inserted.

For example: If you want the following web address to be said slower, enter it as `a, t, t, r, s.gov`

I realize this may not be suitable for some applications, but it definitely works.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I put a longer pause between each word:

//initialize and declare TextToSpeech as tts

//"line" is the String you are trying to speak

```
char ch = '';
String temp = "";

for(int counter = 0; counter < line.length; counter++)
{
    ch = charAt(counter);
    temp = temp + ch;

    if(ch == ' ' || counter == (line.length() - 1))
    {
        tts.speak(temp, TextToSpeech.QUE_ADD, null, null);
        tts.playSilentUtterance(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD,null);
        temp = "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding '/ / / / /' to your text. It should give you it some breathing room. If you want a longer pause, try adding more.

Answer (score -1):

You can split you sentence in words and speak them in a for loop in a new thread. Splitting the phrase will give you a little delay, but if you want a longer one you could work on thread and make them wait.
It would be something like this:

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
String[] words = text.split(" ");
for (final CharSequence word : words) {
    Runnable t = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            m_TTS.speak(word, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null, "TTS_ID");

        }
    };
    h.postDelayed(t, 1000);
}
```

Comment: What is "TTS_ID"?

Comment: It is an identifier defined by the developer. See the official https://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#speak(java.lang.CharSequence, int, android.os.Bundle, java.lang.String).