# How to make a pause button for Android Text-to-speech?

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

I'm a newbie in android dev and this is my first time in stackoverflow.

Im currently developing a simple workout app for my Software Engineering subject and I implemented Text-to-Speech to read out the workout steps.
I have a button named "Play/Pause Audio"

This is my onclick listener:

```
  speak.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!tts.isSpeaking()) {
                HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, "sampletext");
                tts.speak(tv.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, params);
            } else {
                tts.stop();
            }
        }
    });
```

But when i try to pause it, it stops and restarts the process. 
 Is there a way to pause TTS?
Thank you so much!!

Comment: You can use [TextToSpeech.playSilence()](https://github.com/gast-lib/gast-lib/blob/master/app/src/root/gast/playground/speech/tts/TextToSpeechDemo.java) also you can take a look on [this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-text-to-speech-implementing-pause-and-resume-in-tts-using-mediaplayer/)

Comment: Please look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970204/how-to-pause-android-speech-tts-texttospeech

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the `playSilence()` method to pause:

```
public void pause(long duration){
        tts.playSilence(duration, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
```

Where `duration` is in milliseconds.

So calling for example, `pause(5000)` will pause for 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

You can't!

After the call of speak, the TextToSpeech will play for you the generated audio.

But, you can generate the audio in a File using  [synthesizeToFile](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#synthesizeToFile%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20android.os.Bundle,%20java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%29)  and play it.