# Make voice pause between phrases on Android (TalkBack and Text-To-Speech)

Tags: android, string, text-to-speech, talkback

I am setting the content description for a TextView using setContentDescription method.

The string passed to this method is a concatenation of two sentences separated by a period "."

When TalkBack ot TTS (Text-To-Speech) read this, it does not mark a pause between the two sentences.

My question is, is there a some way to handle this, a special UTF character for example ?

Answer (score 4):

Try a newline charachter.

To read this barcode: "3S REGR 2345", I found that "3 S\nR E G R\n2 3 4 5" got me the result I was after on Samsung TTS.

It will be read as "Three S. R E G R. Two Three Four Five"

Comment: Nice solution! I was using a comma separator but it caused some strange pronunciation issues. New line character seems to work well. Thanks!

Comment: this solution works with jetpack compose as well. good one!

Answer (score 1):

Uncertain if there is any special character available, but another solution might be to split the speech and add

```
textToSpeech.playSilence(750, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
```

then continue with the rest of the split

Comment: For more information you can also take a look at the following questions answer [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4970204/how-to-pause-android-speech-tts-texttospeech]

Comment: Thanks

Yes, this should work for TTS. But I wanted a solution that works for both TTS and TalkBack (that's why I asked if there is a special character that is understood by both of these voice tools)